# Detecting scroll to bottom - disable up/down scrolling buttons with return

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have this content div that as a lot of stuff in it - headers, paragraphs, tables, images, etc - which is scrollable through an **up** and **down** buttons.

The buttons have a mousenter, mouseleave, mousedown and *mouseup* events. I want the mousevents to be disabled - return - when they reach their respective up/down limits. So I did this (down button):

```
$('.compositos_infoBtnDown').on('mouseenter', function(){
    if ($('.compositos_infoContent').scrollTop() + $('.compositos_infoContent').height() == $('.compositos_infoContent').height()){
      return;
    }
    // Mousenter animation
  });

  $('.compositos_infoBtnDown').on('mouseleave', function(){
    // Mousleave animation
  });

  $('.compositos_infoBtnDown').on('mousedown', function(){
    if ($('.compositos_infoContent').scrollTop() + $('.compositos_infoContent').height() == $('.compositos_infoContent').height()){
      return;
    }
    // Mousdown animation
    // Scroll code (working fine)
  });

  $('.compositos_infoBtnDown').on('mouseup', function(){
    if ($('.compositos_infoContent').scrollTop() + $('.compositos_infoContent').height() == $('.compositos_infoContent').height()){
      return;
    }
    // Mousdown animation
    // Scroll code (working fine)
  });
```

The HTML structure:

```
<div class="compositos_infoContainer">
  <div class="compositos_infoContent">
    <h3>...</h3>
    <p>...</p>
    <div>...</div>
    <table>...</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

(The **scrollTop** is being used on the *Scroll code (working fine)*, of course.)
I got the up button working great:

```
if ($('.compositos_infoContent').scrollTop() === 0){
      return;
    }
```

... the problem is with the down button.

The if statement doesn't work, of course. How can I fix this?

Thanx in advance.

Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found how to do it:

```
if ($('.compositos_infoContent').scrollTop() + $('.compositos_infoContent').innerHeight() >= $('.compositos_infoContent')[0].scrollHeight){
      return;
    }
```

Hope it helps anyone.

Pedro